# Attempt to set "sep" / "dec" ignored: Error in write.csv format - R

Tags: r, csv

There are similar posts, but none of them actually explained what is this error cause by?

I would like to obtain input in this .csv format: separator ";" and decimal "."

```
Parameter;Intensitaet;Wert
se;1;0.027
se;1;0.024
se;1;0.021
se;1;0.018
se;1;0.015
se;1;0.012
```

What I get is:

```
Parameter;Intensitaet;Wert
se;2;0,0572
se;2;0,2
se;2;0,1
se;2;0,4
se;2;0,0795
```

The have tried various versions of this code:

```
> write.csv(final, "SEmurgang.csv", row.names = F, quote = F, sep = ";")
Warning message:
In write.csv(final, "SEmurgang.csv", row.names = F, quote = F, sep = ";") :
  Versuch ignoriert 'sep' zu setzen

> write.csv2(final, "SEmurgang.csv", row.names = F, quote = F, dec=".")
Warning message:
In write.csv2(final, "SEmurgang.csv", row.names = F, quote = F,  :
  Versuch ignoriert 'dec' zu setzen
```

However, I always get the same error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `write.table` instead?

Comment: [manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Decimal and separator are hard coded in `write.csv2`.

> write.csv2 uses a comma for the decimal point and a semicolon for the
> separator, the Excel convention for CSV files in some Western European
> locales.

If they do not suit you, you are better of using `write.table`.

`write.table` is the basic method and `write.csv` and kin are just a handy wrappers.

Using `write.table` works for me.

```
 xy <- data.frame(Parameter = rep("se", 5),
                 Intensitaet = rep(1, 5),
                 Wert = rnorm(5))
 xy
  Parameter Intensitaet         Wert
1        se           1 -1.014570811
2        se           1 -0.680449323
3        se           1 -0.223736133
4        se           1  0.004270224
5        se           1  0.607427274

 write.table(xy, file = "test.txt", row.names = FALSE, dec = ".", sep = ";", 
              quote = FALSE)
 
system("cat test.txt")
Parameter;Intensitaet;Wert
se;1;-1.01457081089331
se;1;-0.68044932280397
se;1;-0.223736133320336
se;1;0.0042702235293986
se;1;0.607427274081342
```

Comment: I think you should include the relevant details about how `write.csv` is designed to ignore certain arguments....

Comment: Yes this work indeed. Thank you @Roman Luštrik. But why wouldn't write.csv work? what is causing the error?

Comment: @Danka because the parameter you want to modify are not meant to be modified in `write.csv2` or `write.csv`. The warnings you are getting are more than clear: "Versuch *ignoriert* 'dec' zu setzen". Just use `write.table`.

Answer (score -2):

```
format(df, digits = 3, trim = TRUE)
```

The `trim = TRUE` argument will remove extra space.